# How to define a font face in mark up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I have a font face declared like this in .erb file

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'robotoslab';
    src: url("file://#{Rails.root.join('app', 'tmp', 'fonts', 'RobotoSlab-Thin.ttf')}");
  }
</style>
```

And I am calling it like this

```
h5 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: 'robotoslab';
    font-size: 10px;
  }
```

All the other properties are getting applied except font-family. Also I am sure that font file is the path

```
Rails.root.join('app', 'tmp', 'fonts', 'RobotoSlab-Thin.ttf')
=> #<Pathname:/home/vamsi/code/certificate_generator/app/tmp/fonts/RobotoSlab-Thin.ttf>
```

I am having this in tmp folder because of pdfkit does not like assest pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You have to encapsulate it in `<%= %>`.

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'robotoslab';
    src: url("file://<%= Rails.root.join('app', 'tmp', 'fonts', 'RobotoSlab-Thin.ttf') %>");
  }
</style>
```

But I'm not sure if this works since you load the font via the `file://` protocol. You probably want to load it via `http`. If so simply remove `file://`.

Comment: The provided snippet and the removing file:// did not work. I even tried having base64 version of the ttf file in the url That also did not work lol

Comment: @gates Could you add the output in the browser to the question?

Comment: well it's not about browser, in browser a cdn for robot slab will also work, but I am using pdfkit

Comment: Ah ok, haven't seen that you want to output a pdf with that.